# Not able to publish multi project builds using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to publish multi project gradle(3 build.gradle) project in nexus in jenkins pipeline

If same build version present any of the sub project entire build is failing in jenkins(Nexus won't publish artifats having same version).How to Publish the artifacts of subproject which build version is different without failing jenkins pipeline

Comment: Are you asking how to skip the publish task for an artifact that already exists in Nexus with the same version?

Comment: I have  three sub project which is having version number. I want to publish only the projects having new version number